# CakePHP, route to a view based on time of day

Tags: cakephp, date, datetime, time, routes

I'm working on developing a mobile site for a restaurant, and looking to perform a route based off of the time of day.

So, for example, if its 1pm, by default the app routes to the lunch menu.
If it's 2am, the app routes to the late-night menu.

Any idea how to do this within the **Cake 2.X Framework**?

Answer (score 2):

I would implement a custom router that handles this, to keep things clean and "Cakey".

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes

Or you can just add some conditions in your routes config.  Something like below, but obviously I don't know your exact routes.  The time logic would be similar, whichever method you choose to us.

**app/Config/routes.php**

```
$hour = date('G');

if ($hour >= 13 && $hour < 18) {
    $menu = 'lunch';
} elseif ($hour >= 18 || $hour < 2) {
    $menu = 'dinner';
} elseif ($hour >= 2 && $hour < 6) {
    $menu = 'late';
} else {
    $menu = 'breakfast';
}

Router::connect('/menu', array('controller' => 'menus', 'action' => $menu));
```

Answer (score -1):

Something to consider is whether this logic should be in your routes file. To me this logic belongs to a model, i.e. you would have a `getMenu($hour)` method which returns the menu depending on the time.